# Find a value in Excel in the rightest place?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table for example:

```
    A         B        C        D
1  Value1
2  Value2   Value1
3  Value1   Value3  Value4
4  Value2
```

Is there any way to find the value on the rightes place in a row?
For example is there a way  to get the values from each rows from column A..D?

With this wanted solution I would get:

```
Value1
Value1
Value4
Value2
```

Is there any excel formula to get this wanted solution?

Comment: Try:  `=INDEX(A2:D2,MATCH("ZZZ",A2:D2))` if values are text . Else replace "ZZZ" with 1e+99.

Comment: Is `Value1` a string or a number/date? Are they ALL strings or numbers/dates or mixed?

Comment: It is a string, for example week numbers: 16w1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this formula and adjust the range **1:1** as necessary to avoid circular references:

```
=LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),1:1)
```

[image]

Comment: To supplement this, I would add that to find a number or date you would look for an impossibly large number instead of an impossibly long string; e.g. `=LOOKUP(1e99, 1:1)`